# Is there any way to change the colour of header in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to change colour of window form header. Is there any way to do so?

[image: Window form colour]

Comment: I think pygame can't do that, only the operating system can modify the caption. See [this page](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/19150-change-title-bar-text-size-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that from with in the Pygame application, only the operating system can modify color of the title bar. See [How to Change Text Size for Title Bars in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/19150-change-title-bar-text-size-windows-10-a.html)